# NativeModule RNCGeolocation is null

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I upgraded to react native 60 and with it came Pods. Its too late to revert now. I get the error

> @react-native-community/geolocation NativeModule.RNCGeolocation is Null.

Ive linked the module, uninstall reinstall module, uninstall node modules and reinstall, pod install, created new projects etc etc

Comment: did you update the import statement to something like this?
import Geolocation from "@react-native-community/geolocation";

Comment: yes but I still receive the same error after importing Geolocation from @react-native-community/geolocation

Comment: make sure that you have geolocation folder in node_modules/@react-native-community

Comment: I do have these files yet the error still persists, do you have any other suggestions I can try

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was actually using another library, which depended on `@react-native-community/gelocation`, which was `react-native-geolocation-service`. I didn't actually follow the installation steps for this. When I did, it worked. I guess since you're upgrading and have unlinked, you need to add this to the Podfile, as it **might not support autolinking.**

For RN version > 0.60, from [geolocation service docs](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service),

> Update your 'Podfile' (Add the following to the Podfile)
>
> ```
> `pod 'react-native-geolocation', path: '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'`
> ```
>
> Then run `pod install` from ios directory

Answer (score 1):

I'm building my app on an android device and I had the same issue!
This is what solved my issue:
1: `npm i 'react-native-geolocation-service`

2: Changing this in "app.js"

```
// import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
```

Here's the link to the issue on github: [native-geolocation/issues](https://github.com/michalchudziak/react-native-geolocation/issues/93#issuecomment-773436327)